# Syntax error near unexpected token `='()

Tags: bash, sh

I'm running some legacy code on bash shell and I'm having trouble understanding/passing through this line:

```
BASH_FUNC_module()='() {  eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*`
}'; export BASH_FUNC_module()
```

The error I get is:

```
line 364: syntax error near unexpected token `='() {  eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*`
}''
line 364: `}'; export BASH_FUNC_module()'
```

Any pointers would be appreciated, I'm new to shell :) Thanks!

Comment: What shell are you using? `sh` is pretty generic. Is it `bash`? `csh`? `zsh`? Other? Do you know what system the legacy code came from?

Comment: @lurker Hi lurker, I think it's `bash`. Sorry not sure about the code, I don't think I was supposed to dig deep to start with...

Comment: You can look up function definition in bash and fix the syntax.

Comment: Why is there a new line? I think it should be one command on the first line ended by a semicolon, then `export` starting on the next line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you're trying to convert some trace/dump output of bash.  most likely you want:

```
module() { eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*`; }
export -f module
```

that should work on old/new versions of bash.

Comment: Probably what's required is to define `module()` - the `BASH_FUNC_` prefix is an artefact of how Bash stores functions in the environment (which is at the, er, _heart_ of the Heartbleed vulnerability).

Comment: true -- dropped that syntax prefix

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly combining the syntax for assignment and function definitions.

```
BASH_FUNC_module='() { eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*`; }'
export BASH_FUNC_module
```

Answer (score 0):

Mike Frysinger correctly describes the problem *cause*.  However, *solving* the problem generally requires one of several steps:

- Uninstall the offending package, usually named **environment-modules**,
- Modify the legacy code to skip environment variables that begin w/"**BASH_FUNC_**",
- Remove it from your environment before running the legacy code with: `unset -f module`

More generally, to unset all exported functions you could use the following:

`unset -f $(env | awk '/^BASH_FUNC_/{sub("[(].*","");print substr($0,11)}')`

Of course:

- uninstalling the package will not alter the current shell.
- the `unset -f` command also has the effect of removing the function(s) from the current shell.